# Cannot exit debugger on running cordova app on ios device

Tags: cordova

I used the command "cordova run ios" to run my app on my ios device but i am unable to shutdown the debugger (lldb) in terminal. I tried Ctrl+C but nothing happened. Could someone please tell me how to stop it. For now i end up closing terminal just to get around it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

write `quit` in terminal,press enter. If it asks for `y/n` write `y` press enter

Comment: is this outdated? Cause it's not working.

Comment: This works with 1.3.2 for me.  Funny, I didn't know lldb was actually a prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue. You can try updating ios-deploy like this other answer says:

[how to stop after "cordova run ios"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122380/how-to-stop-after-cordova-run-ios)

I already have the latest ios-deploy version and still it's not working.

Steps:

It is probably because of an earlier version of ios-deploy, as it is described here.

Check your version of ios-deploy, mine was 1.0.8:

```
$ ios-deploy --version
```

Check npm version of ios-deploy, current is 1.1.0:

```
$ npm info ios-deploy version
```

Update ios-deploy via npm:

```
$ sudo npm update -g ios-deploy
```

After $ cordova run you can now type exit and y to exit the process.

also refer git issues page:

https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy/issues/38