# how to stop after "cordova run ios"

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3

What is the command to stop running after using `cordova run ios` in terminal?

I found one topic about this with 1 answer saying it's `quit` but that didn't work. 
Right now I close terminal every time which is very time consuming.

If i press ctrl+c I get the following:

> (lldb) ^CTraceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/private/tmp/fruitstrap_.py", line 17, in connect_command
>       event = lldb.SBEvent()   File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Python/lldb/**init**.py",
>   line 3395, in **init**
>       this = _lldb.new_SBEvent(*args) KeyboardInterrupt error: the platform is not currently connected Executing commands in
>   '/tmp/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-'. (lldb)      platform select
>   remote-ios --sysroot '/Users/doekewartena/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS
>   DeviceSupport/7.1.2 (11D257)/Symbols'   Platform: remote-ios 
>   Connected: no   SDK Path:
>   "/Users/doekewartena/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/7.1.2
>   (11D257)/Symbols" (lldb)      target create
>   "/Users/doekewartena/Documents/jbc2014/platforms/ios/build/device/JBC2014.app"
>   Current executable set to
>   '/Users/doekewartena/Documents/jbc2014/platforms/ios/build/device/JBC2014.app'
>   (armv7). (lldb)      script
>   fruitstrap_device_app="/private/var/mobile/Applications/E23498AF-29C5-4A9F-8AFB-6566631DB725/JBC2014.app"
>   (lldb)      script fruitstrap_connect_url="connect://127.0.0.1:12345"
>   (lldb)      command script import "/tmp/fruitstrap_.py" (lldb)
>   command script add -f fruitstrap_.connect_command connect (lldb)
>   command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_.run_command run
>   (lldb)      command script add -s asynchronous -f
>   fruitstrap_.autoexit_command autoexit (lldb)      connect (lldb)
>   run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode shouldn't be running if you are building your project using cordova cli. This will most likely solve your problem.

Answer (score 8):

It is probably because of an earlier version of `ios-deploy`, as it is described [here](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy/issues/38).

Check your version of ios-deploy, mine was 1.0.8:

```
$ ios-deploy --version
```

Check npm version of ios-deploy, current is 1.1.0:

```
$ npm info ios-deploy version
```

Update ios-deploy via npm:

```
$ sudo npm update -g ios-deploy
```

After `$ cordova run` you can now type `exit` and press ENTER. After this, type `y` and press ENTER to exit the process.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation but sadly it didn't work.
My version was also 1.0.8 and now it's 1.1.0 but exit still doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 7):

Having tried lots of different suggestions, the only thing that's worked for me is having another terminal window open, and when you're finished with the debugging run:

`pkill lldb`

That will close the app on the phone, and also return the original terminal window the command prompt neatly.

Answer (score 3):

I enter "exit" and then press Y and hit enter. This works when it stops at lldb.

Comment: Right solution... If you just press Ctrl-C, the session is aborted but the whole script crashes and you might have problems starting a new session

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ctrl-C after the debug phase but before it says (lldb) it will exit...

Answer (score 0):

Simply press `CTRL+C` (in most unix shells)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still finding this is an issue with Cordova 5.1.1 CLI.

I found pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the terminal window running lldb worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that depends on the way I run the app.

If I run the app using `phonegap run ios`, I must press `Ctrl + C`; but if I run using `cordova run ios`, I can also exit typing `quit` or `exit` in `lldb` (after the app runs), and then press `Y`.

As a side note: When I exit pressing `Ctrl + C`, and then unplug my device and delete the app, after plug my device again `lldb` attempt to install the app again, without asking. That does not happen when I exit typing `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when running `ionic cordova run browser`. pushing `CTRL-C` just killed the terminal process but server was running in the background.

My solution on the mac was to go to activity monitor and kill process called `node`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Command + C` if you're using terminal on Mac.