# "Valid signing identity not found" for development Xcode 5.1.1 Cordova

Tags: cordova, xcode5

Xcode's organizer always says "Valid signing identity not found" for every device for the existing provisioning profiles or if I add new ones. I've tried deleting provisioning profiles and creating new ones using Apple's iOS developer site and downloading them. I've tried using "Add to Member Center" on the device page. I've tried adding and deleting certificates. I've tried restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you created and downloaded your certificates, you have to select them for use in `Build Settings`

[image: Add certificate]

Comment: Hi I have no xcodeproj file or project - I'm using "cordova run ios" in the Terminal to deploy the cordova app to my iPod. I just went back to my home computer and had the same errors (because I deleted my original provisioning profiles) then I went to the device then "Add to Member Center" and the provisioning profiles now both say "Valid Profile". But I want it to also work on my work computer.

Comment: You need to run `cordova build ios` first, afterwards Cordova will generate an xcodeproj file, from which you can build and preview your app on your device.

Comment: Thanks I eventually got it to work though I couldn't find the "Code Signing" section. Now I have the following problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122380/how-to-stop-after-cordova-run-ios it seems like I have to exit the terminal and restart it again each time.

Comment: Can you type `npm info ios-deploy version` and tell me what do you see? If it's anything BELOW 1.0.9, then you need to follow @Loki's instructions http://stackoverflow.com/a/25156110/541591